# Selenium click a button contain both class and ng-class

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to use selenium to click a button that contain both ng-class and class attribute.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu7nj.png)

I have tried to do code as follows

```
clickNextButton = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="col-xs-100.default-button-height.menu-button"]');

clickNextButton.click()
```

and

```
clickNextButton = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="col-xs-100 default-button-height menu-button"]');
clickNextButton.click()
```

However it both returned Unable to locate element

Is there a way for the button to be clicked?

Comment: Were you able to identify the object using any of above xpath in browser DOM? I believe the xpath doesn’t work properly when it has multiple values. Same button element can be identified using css selector *button.menu-button*

Comment: Please share text based HTML rather than image.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below XPath expression and see if it works:

```
//button[contains(@class,'col-xs-100 default-button-height menu-button')]
```

Or this:

```
//div[@data-toggle='dropdown']//button
```